# Angular 8 karma test a service without injecting all service in the constructor

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, angular8, angular-test

I'm new to Angular testing with Karma and I'm not understanding how to properly test a service.
Let's say I have this service that I have to test:

```typescript
    @Injectable()
    export class MyService {
        constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

        //methods to test
    }
```

and this is my test class:

```typescript
    describe('MyService', () => {
      let service: MyService;
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [MyService],
        }).compileComponents();
        service = TestBed.get(MyService);
      }));
    });
```

When I run ng test it gives the error `NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpService!`.
So I add HttpService into providers array in test class, this way:

```typescript
    describe('MyService', () => {
      let service: MyService;
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [MyService, HttpService],
        }).compileComponents();
        service = TestBed.get(MyService);
      }));
    });
```

HttpService is this:

```typescript
    @Injectable()
    export class HttpService{
        constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }
    }
```

So now I get the error `NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!`. (HttpClient is from @angular/common/http).
If I add HttpClient to providers array in test class then I get the same error for all the services/class inside HttpClient constructor, and so on. What is the correct way to instatiate a service, without having to add each providers, leading to potential infinite providers?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Testbed configuration, import `HttpClientTestingModule`

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [MyService, HttpService],
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
  }));
```

You may consider also

1. changing `TestBed.get(MyService);` to `TestBed.inject(MyService);` as `TestBed.get(...)` is deprecated [What's the difference between TestBed.get and new Service(...dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776234/whats-the-difference-between-testbed-get-and-new-service-dependencies)
2. changing `async` to `waitForAsync` as `async` is deprecated [When to use waitForAsync in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384279/when-to-use-waitforasync-in-angular)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. So this solution is specific for my case, but is there a right way to test services in general, without having to import all the services it uses? Like a common way that avoids the import chain?

Answer (score 2):

you should use `HttpClientTestingModule` and mock data with `HttpTestingController` and the `flush` method. this is an example with **Angular 11** and **jasmine 3.6.0** about how I test services. I hope it helps you:

```
// Dependencies
import { TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

// Assets
import { ExampleService } from './api/example.service';

describe('*[Example Service]: -----------------------------------------', () => {
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
    let service: ExampleService;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
             HttpClientTestingModule
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        
      httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
      service = TestBed.inject(ExampleService);
    }));
    
    it('1). should get data from GET service', waitForAsync( () => {
      // Arrange
      const expectedData: string[] = ['data1', 'data2'];
      let apiError, apiData;
      // Action
      service.getData().subscribe(response => {
        apiData = response;
      }, error => {
        apiError = error;
      });
      const request = httpTestingController.expectOne(`http://localhost:3000/example`);
      request.flush(expectedData);
      // Assert
      expect(apiData.length).toEqual(2);
      expect(apiError).toBeUndefined();
        }));

});
```